# dns record resolution - weirdness

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I have an AD integrated forward DNS zone say domain.com. when I try to query a specific record in the zone like  ie.domain.com it gives me answer that it's CNAME pointing to www.domain.com.

When I open the DNS Management console, I don't see this record at all.

I cleared the server cache.
I created A record with same name and it let me create, but it still continued to resolve to earlier CNAME.
I created CNAME record with same name and it let me create, but it still continued to resolve to earlier CNAME.

I also looked at querying the record using dnscmd.exe /enumrecords command
I also looked at backend AD location (ForestDNSZone) and there also there is no such record.
I also verified there are no conditional forwarder for this domain on the server.

I am stumped right now, from where DNS server is getting that CNAME record?

Comment: You're querying the domain controller directly, right?

Comment: Yes.. infact I tried to query multiple domain controllers to just make sure it had nothing to do with Replication.

Comment: Did you flush the DNS Cache on the client?

Comment: Yes I had cleared the cache on client too.

Comment: Have you manually forced nslookup to query the server with the zone using "server <ip address>"? If this works you may have an issue with the wrong DNS servers set on the computer you're testing from.

Comment: Is there a wildcard entry in the zone that is mapped to the CNAME (record "*")?

Comment: No there is no wildcard entry... I forgot to mention it but I did verify that by trying to resolve other non-existing names, which all failed.

Comment: @AshleySteel Yes I have tried different DNS servers... I have even tried using dig and it also gives the same results

Comment: What is the specific record on the domain that you are querying? It could be reserved somehow?

Comment: Can you confirm the computer you're testing from is not infected with something? The DNS queries might be going via some other server without your knowledge. Perhaps setup some packet sniffing using Wireshark?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that subdomain was independently hosted with different AD replication scope and no delegation done in parent domain.

I knew that where zone is hosted (domain, DOmainDNSZone or ForestDNSZones) mattered in terms of where server looks up for data and looking at other partitions gave me the clue.

Comment: since you answered the question, may I suggest that you mark it as the answer :)